# Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed in a subroutine

Tags: vba, excel

When I run this code, I get the following error:

> Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Public Sub go()

Dim c As Range
Dim w As Integer
Dim h As Integer
Dim rowloop As Integer
Dim colloop As Integerr
Dim filename As String
filename = Range("configuration!excelfilename").Value

Windows(myfile).Activate

Worksheets("outputs").Range("A2:AK30").Clear
Sheets("api").Cells.ClearContents
w = Range("testcases").Columns.Count
h = Range("testcases").Rows.Count
'o = Range("outputs").Columns.Count

Sheets("outputs").Select
Range("A2").Select ' this decides the initial cell into which we will paste the first copy/paste operation in outputs

For rowloop = 2 To h 'iterate over each of the rows of inputs beginning with row 2
    result = "PASS: "
    Json = ""
    For colloop = 1 To w ' first fill in all the inputs to the spreadsheet building the JSON for api as you go
        Call PasteInput(Range("testcases")(colloop)(1), Range("testcases")(colloop)(rowloop))

'above PasteInput function call my below subroutine
     Sub PasteInput(input_name As Variant, v As Variant)
    filename = Range("configuration!excelfilename").Value
    Windows(filename & ".xlsx").Activate

    Range(input_name).Value = v     ['error highlight on this line]
    Windows(myfile).Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Where did you define input_name, beyong declaring as variant?  same for myfile, which isn't given a dimension.

Comment: What values are you passing for `input_name` and `v`? As an initial guess, I'd suspect that it's having trouble converting `input_name` to a valid range.

Comment: @DavidP my input values are taken from named range called testcases defined in my spreadsheet

Comment: You're not giving us much to go on. What are the values that you're passing?

Comment: Please read [mcve]: your question isn't really answerable if we can't reproduce the problem you're having with the information you're giving us.

Comment: @JainP what are the actual values themselves, not where they are located in your sheet.

Comment: @DavidP input_name value is a string "zip code" and v is 60015 as integer

Comment: Names for ranges cannot contain spaces, so "zip code" is not a valid name. Check name manager to ensure it's defined correctly and try "zipcode" or "zip_code" instead.

Answer (score 0):

Stepping through and debugging will be your friend. Using `debug.print` lines to indicate when you reach certain points in the code will be of great help for you.

Using `Option Explicit` is important and will probably allow the system to provide comments that are a little more helpful and will also enable debugging.

You call ranges based on names (`Named Ranges`). `filename = Range("configuration!excelfilename").Value` is calling an illegal name.

But your main error is that you are calling a named range that does not exist. Up to you to debug to find out why you are passing a bad name to use as a named range.

In addition, check that the named ranges exist in your active sheet. Because you have not specified your worksheet.

Having said that, there are multiple other errors in your code that means that, even after fixing the above you will still have errors. I am surprised that you even got the code to run far enough to give the error (the compiler should have baulked at the `For` without `Next` and the `Sub` within the `Sub`). I expect that we will see other new questions from you as you work through the code!